# Rhino Mocks Testing Lambda Expression

Tags: c#, unit-testing, lambda, rhino-mocks

I want to make sure the expression in lambda is same as expected expression

Also I want to write test case for expected value

If I write match it is not working

**For example**

```
public bool IsUserActive(User user)
{
    userRepository.Any(x=>x.UserId== user.UserId && x.IsActive);
}
```

**Unit test Case**

```
userRepository.Stub(x=>x.IsActive(Arg<User>.Matches(y=>y.IsActive)).Return(true);
```

The above expression is not working

I have seen the example but I want to test some lambda expression that return bool by checking condition

not the user name string

```
stubUserRepository.Stub(x =>
  x.GetUserByName(Arg<string>.Matches(y =>
    y.StartsWith("aye", StringComparison.InvariantCulture) 
      || y.StartsWith("stein", StringComparison.InvariantCulture)))
  .Return(theUser);
Assert.AreSame(theUser, stubUserRepository.GetUserByName("steinegger"));
Assert.AreSame(theUser, stubUserRepository.GetUserByName("ayende"));
```

Comment: Rather than asserting that a lambda matches exactly to a lambda that you expect it to you, you should be testing that the method outputs the value that you expect for each of various different types of inputs.  Testing that the code written is the code that you wrote isn't particularly productive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use AbstractConstraint attribute

```
public class UserConstraint :AbstractConstraint
```

and override Equal to match contstraint

```
  _dataSericeValidator.AssertWasCalled(
                x =>
                    x.ValidateRequestUser(Arg<UserDto>.Matches(new UserConstraint (_userDto))));
```